# Primary Key - Foreign Key relationship between two different database

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, hibernate, database-design

I am working on oracle SQL 11g database. Here I have two different user/database -

1. usrMgmt
2. application

Under **usrMgmt** database I have a table **ROLE** and Under **application** database I have a table **PROOFING_LOG**. The **PROOFING_LOG** table has a column ROLE_ID which contain the ID of ROLE table. Can I make a primary key foreign key relationship with ROLE.ID and PROOFING_LOG.ROLE_ID?
Thanks

**UPDATE:**
Does hibernate provide any support for this type of mapping?

Answer (score 1):

```
grant references on usrMgmt.role TO application;
```

see [Ask Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3A%3A%3A%3AP11_QUESTION_ID:60443882718790)